# Augment function type's argument by index

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So, this tricky function takes a function `fn` and a number `n` and returns a wrapper function that calls `fn` with a modified `n`th argument. The `n`th argument of `fn` is an object whose `plugins` property is an array of `PluginObject` objects whereas the `n`th argument of the returned function should have a slightly different type: its `plugins` property is `Array<string | PluginObject>`, also it can have an optional `pluginSearchDirs: string[]` property, the rest of the properties are taken from the type of the `n`th argument of the original `fn` function.

The question is how on Earth can I convert this to TypeScript?

```js
function withPlugins(fn, n) {
    return (...args) => {
        const opts = args[n];
        args[n] = {
            ...opts,
            plugins: loadPlugins(opts.plugins, opts.pluginSearchDirs)
        };
        return fn(...args);
    };
}
```

Here's what I tried, but it didn't work (`withPlugins(myFn, 0)` has the same type as `myFn`, [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)):

```js
interface PluginObject {
  foo: any;
}

declare function loadPlugins(
  plugins?: (PluginObject | string)[],
  pluginSearchDirs?: string[]
): PluginObject[];

function withPlugins<
  Args extends any[],
  Result,
  OptsIdx extends number
>(
  fn: (...args: Args) => Result,
  optsArgIdx: OptsIdx
): (
  ...args: {
    [P in keyof Args]: OptsIdx extends P
      ? Args[P] & {
          plugins: (PluginObject | string)[];
          pluginSearchDirs?: string[];
        }
      : Args[P];
  }
) => Result {
  return (...args) => {
    const opts = args[optsArgIdx];
    args[optsArgIdx] = {
      ...opts,
      plugins: loadPlugins(opts.plugins, opts.pluginSearchDirs)
    };
    return fn(...args as any);
  };
}
```